# Tagline does not appear on the Iphone for facebook application when post to user wall?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook application that can post (message,link,image) to user wall
The tagline(via status appname) does not appeared when I see the userwall or homepage

**This is the code**:

```
          // in case of image
        $image = "image url"
        $attachment = array(
            'message' => $message,
            'source' => $image,
            'url' => $image
        );
        $photo = true;
   // in case of youtube link
        $attachment = array(
            'message' => $message,
            'link' => 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $video_id,
            'source' => 'http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $video_id,
            'description' => $description,
            'picture' => 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $video_id . '/0.jpg',
        );
    //incase of text
        $attachment = array(
            'message' => $message,
            'name' => $title,
        );
    }
foreach($users as $uid=>$token){
    $attachment['access_token'] = $token;
    if (isset($photo)) {
                $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
                $fb_result = $facebook->api('/' . $uid . '/photos', 'post', $attachment);
            } else {
                $fb_result = $facebook->api('/' . $uid . '/feed/', 'post', $attachment);
            }
}
```